# How to set window position in VB when window is not visible?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, instances

Usually I write in C#, but today im fighting with VB.

I have code like this:

```
FormTest.Left = 1000

If FormTest.Visible Then
    FormTest.BringToFront()
Else
    FormTest.Show()
End If
```

It doesn't work.

When I moved part with setting Left property after Show() - it works.

```
If FormTest.Visible Then
    FormTest.BringToFront()
Else
    FormTest.Show()
End If

FormTest.Left = 1000
```

However, window shows at default location for a moment, then it "moves" to desired location. I want it to show in desired location.

In C# my "typical show window" procedure is diffrent - by using constructor, handling form instances manually etc. I have no idea how I should do this in VB. Please help.

Comment: well heck, you just deleted your last question as I was answering it. Thanks.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry. I wish I could un-delete...

Comment: I undeleted it @HovercraftFullOfEels, if you have that answer copied somewhere - you can post it. If not - sorry I wasted your time, I upvoted few your valuable posts to repay somehow. I think I figured that Java problem myself, however any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, answer re-created. I can show simple code example in some minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
FormTest.Left = 1000
FormTest.Visible = True
FormTest.BringToFront()
```

And if you want the window to start at the position you want when you use `.Show()` then:

```
FormTest.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
```

With this way it will start on the position you specified from the beggining.

Comment: First suggestion not helped, but when I set StartPosition property to Manual before .Show - it helped. Thanks.